# How to Make a Scala databricks Notebook on Spark Run Faster, More Performant

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

```
val df1= spark.read.format("delta").table("...100K_rows...")

val xform = udf ( (message: String) => {
 // abstract transformation, ideally this comes from a .jar library
 // such as: (abstract) https://github.com/cosmycx/scala_transformer
  val t0 = System.currentTimeMillis
  Thread.sleep(5)  
  System.currentTimeMillis - t0 
}) // .xformText 
spark.udf.register("xform", xform)

val df2= df1.withColumn("xformResult", xform($"SomeText"))

df2.write.format("delta")
    .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
    .saveAsTable("...")
```

How can this be made to run faster?

What I tried:

- increase the databricks spark cluster node size: DS3_v2 14GB 4 cores vs. DS5_v2 56GB 16 cores
- increase the databricks spark cluster workers numbers, driver plus: 3, 5, and 10 (same speed !?)
- changing: spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "auto") or different values

Results are always in this range: 1 min for 10K rows, and 8 min for 100K rows no matter the changes.

Ideal results would be less than 1 min for 100K+. would this even be achievable in databricks spark?
This runs in Azure if it matters.

What I'm I missing, other things to consider, try? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transform happens sequentially and not concurrent because the df1 DataFrame only has one partition.
Repartitioning the initial DataFrame and then run the transformation the new partitioned DataFrame improves significantly the speed, performance, by a factor of at least 10X.

```
println(df1.rdd.getNumPartitions) // 1

val df2 = df1.repartition(20) // run transform on df2 (100K rows in 35 sec.)
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, this is probably not a use case for spark. The dataset is small that the spark optimizer doesn't even know what to do with it.

What happens is the file is small and read by a single task, spark identifies the transformation as simple and applies it while reading the data - so you process things sequentially and waiting the total 8 minutes of Thread.sleep()

The best think is probably not to use spark for this - but if you do try to make spark do a shuffle (sort or whatever) and make sure your code runs after the shuffle so then you'd have x (200 by default) partitions and can run with up to x different task (but again - I wouldn't use Spark for this)

Comment: I think something like this is the issue also, spark does the work sequentially and does not fan out to worker nodes. I will try to sort the ingest df1 on some column then apply the transform... if I understand right this. 
Regarding use case 100K rows let's say every couple of hours can still add up to millions++  rows dataset pretty quick. I guess one could stream with something else faster then use spark only at tail end on the cumulated data only...

Comment: The fact that you are using UDF's here is also important because UDF's are most expensive functions in spark because engine can't apply optimization to them.

Comment: Usually the recommendation is to have fewer large files but in your case  if you have multiple smaller files it will allow spark to read it concurrently